# Non-literal Midrashim

Tags: midrash, literalism

Sometimes I'll hear a Midrash and sometimes people might say, "Well, I don't know if it's meant to be taken literally."

When do we know when Midrashim are speaking metaphorically or when they are telling a real story?

[Related.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4037/does-one-have-to-take-a-midrash-aggadah-literally)

Comment: I need to find it to be sure, but doesn't the Rambam criticize both those who take Midrashim literally and those who dismiss them outright?

Comment: I think the aforementioned More Nevuchim. See answers below. @SethJ

Comment: I'm reading it. It's not so clear where the author is bringing the Rambam and where he is inserting his own ideas. And since it's anonymous ...

Comment: @SethJ Hakdama to More Nevuchim. Beli Neder I'll take a look at it later.

Comment: Could've sworn it was Perush HaMishnayoth.

Comment: @SethJ either way makes sense.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. It asks how to categorize individual midrashim, whereas the other question asks about "midrash" as a seemingly monolithic class (though some of the answers draw distinctions between different types of midrashim). (Can I ping @msh210 here?)

Comment: @Fred The other speaks of "a midrash" as this one does. (Yes, you can.) Let's discuss this in [chat] if you like (but I can't just at the moment).

Comment: @msh210 I agree it ought be reopened (and cleaned up).  The first question ("When do we know...?") is unique, and unlike the other answer, there's no "meta-halakha" of "must we."  The second question is not distinct from the dupe.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76804/must-we-consider-the-gemaras-conclusions-literally-true

Comment: @Alex This question is totally different and necessarily assumes that the answer to that question is no

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The answer [Here](http://www.mesora.org/midrashim.html) here which he says Rambam in the Moreh and the Ramchal are speaking metaphorically

Comment: What does this mean? I can't parse this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Vilna Gaon (Even Shelema 8:26 citing his other works) says:

> The Midrashim that seem to be nonsense (are not so). Within them is held all the secrets.

Just wanted to add this in.

Comment: even that is not in contradistinction to the Rambam and the Ramchal

Comment: How does this answer the question? The question wasnt which Midrashim contain wisdom; it was which are literal.

Answer (score -5):

**Midrashim do not tell true events**

In his work called Chelek, Maimonides writes that those who take Midrashim literary are "fools," while those who reject them out of hand are also "fools." Midrashim are imaginative parables, sermons designed to teach moral lessons. People should mine Midrashim for lessons about proper behavior.

Comment: The Rambam has no work called chelek. You mean his commentary to the chapter in Sanhedrin called Chelek. He also doesn't write what you say he writes. Read it again.

Comment: Actually, he does.

Comment: You seem to have lifted your answer from a paragraph in [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/110219/1739) answer to a different question.

Comment: Does it matter so long as I don’t copy word for word but teach the same basic truth? Is This not what Maimonides says anyway?

Comment: The Rambam there is coming to say that many medrashim are not literal, but that doesn't mean that all medrashim are non-literal. The question is, how do we know when to say that a story in the medrash that could be literal is and when to say that it is a parable.

Comment: I think the Rambam is saying that **all** midrashim (that have imaginative stories that are impossible to be true) are parables designed to teach people about proper behavior. People need to mine midrashim for moral lessons.