# Why did God create a finite world only once?

Tags: creation

As I know, our world is finite in both in space and time.

But God is infinite. Is there any known reason why He created a single, finite world only once in the Eternity?

Comment: How do you know he didn't create others?

Comment: @DoubleAA There is nothing in the Torah about that. I never ever heard anything such this exist in the Judaism. As I know, Judaism is for objective reality, with a very clear distinction between things what do exist, and between things what we "imagine", but I am very far to be a rabbinical authority. :-)

Comment: Rashi on Genesis 1:1?

Comment: Your definition of time is scientific and not human. From a human perspective, every second can be infinite. I.e. every second in olam hazeh is a portal to access the infinity of olam habah. The device that allows us to make the transition between the finite and the infinite is the Torah. So your question can be rephrased, how can an infinite Torah be given into olam hazeh.

Comment: Possibly related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29741

Comment: How do you know that G-d didn't create other worlds, as Double AA said. Hashem is infinite. We might just be one story Hashem has going on. Sure, we're the only ones who have the Torah, and if there are other worlds out there then we shouldn't be concerned with them...and I doubt Hashem would allow us to come in contact with each other.

Comment: Maybe re-ask: Did God create "other finite worlds?".

Comment: @Gavriel I think a "Why God created our world finite?" matches better my question, but it seems meanwhile it is reopened. Anyways, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Technically, we do not **know** that there are no other worlds in this universe nor do we **know** that this is the only universe that Hashem created. The Torah goes from the general to the specific. After the creation of the world, it shows the details of the descendants of Adam and Chava giving the details of the primary descendants of Kayin and Shes. Note that this ends in the details of Noach. After listing the descendants of Noach, the torah goes to Avraham, Yitzchak, and Yaakov followed by the detailed history of Bnai Yisrael. From there, we go into the details of how the Bnai Yisrael are to behave and the significant parts of the journey to Eretz Yisrael.

For example, we are not told of what happened to the descendants of Noach that became the Chinese or any of the other nations that did not interact with Bnai Yisrael. The torah also does not tell us what became of the other children of Avraham that he sent away to the east.

This implies, that the torah would not talk about the inhabitants of other worlds and what they did or did not do.

Answer (score 2):

I think the question is invalid. The Midrash (Bereishis Rabbah 1) says that Hashem created worlds before this one and wiped them out when nobody accepted the Torah in any of them.

Answer (score 0):

The Midrash in Naso 16 says G-d desired a dwelling place in this world; that is why He created it.

G-d doesn't do things for no reason. If He had created another world, there had to be a reason for it.

Also, most importantly, there is the fact that we have the Torah, which is the only Divine truth and gives purpose to this world. If there were to be another world, it would be purposeless without a Torah. And the existence of another Torah means there would be another truth which makes no sense.

Now, there are other worlds, but not physical ones. It is explained all throughout the Zohar about the four spiritual worlds.

The Torah also says, "In the beginning G-d created," which means before that there was no creation that was physical-- that is, because this was the beginning of creation.

The Zohar says that G-d, His Torah, and the Jews are one. How can He create a separate existence from Him that has none of those? It just does not make any sense logically.

You will find statements that are misconstrued by those that believe the world is millions of years old.
 For example, 'Boneh Olimos Umacharivon', which means, He (i.e. G-d) built worlds and destroyed them.
  People explain that to mean that there were physical worlds, but then they were destroyed. However it is really understood to mean the spiritual worlds of Tohu and Tikun.

This is all sourced in kabbala; I just don't have time right now to find the exact sources. When I do, I will post them.

Comment: "God doesn't do things for no reason if he had created another world the had to be a reason for it." Maybe he created another world and had a reason for it.

Comment: "Also most importantly the fact that we have the Torah which is the only Divine truth and gives purpose to this world. So if there were to be another world it would be purposeless without a Torah which means there would be another truth which makes no sense." Maybe they have the Torah also. Or maybe they have a different Torah. After all, the Rishonim tell us that many mitzvot are reactions to particular groups' activities; e.g. not to act like the Egyptans or Canaanites; they could have mitzvot related to their groups.

Comment: Now there is [sic] other worlds but not physical ones. It is explained all over Zohar about the four world's [sic] that are spiritual. Do you have a quote?

Comment: "The Torah also says in the beginning God created which means before that there was no creation that was physical that is because this was the beginning of creation." What are you trying to say?

Comment: "The Zohar says that God his Torah and the Jews are one" where does it say this?

Comment: "how can he create a separate existence from him that has none of those it just does not make any sense logically." Saying that something does not make sense without presenting any arguments is not very convincing.

Comment: "For example boneh olimos [sic] umachachrivon" Where does it say this?

Comment: Any world with different dimensions than ours or an other set of "laws of physics (pun intended)"  would be considered  non physical worlds. So your actual answer is  -- YES!

Comment: however it is really understood to mean the spiritual world's [sic] of tou and tikun" By whom is it understood this way? What are these worlds?

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding the OP's question. He did not ask about earlier civilizations on this planet before Adam and Eve; he asked about different universes. This has nothing to do with the age of the universe.

Comment: The question was why G-d created the world?