# How tall was Adam?

Tags: midrash, adam, size

I once read a post on [Answering-Islam](http://www.answering-islam.org/Responses/Osama/90feet-adam.htm) about the Height of Adam, and it said that the Islamic view of Adam was simple Muhammad copying the Jewish stories/belief's about Adam. As I don't know what stories could possibly be told (nor how to understand them) about Adam and his 'stature', I thought it best to come to the source.

How tall was Adam, according to Judaism?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rashi ([Baba Batra 75A](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=23&daf=75&format=pdf)) explains that both [@DoubleAA](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18569/603) and [@ba](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18568/603) are correct.

The Talmud [(Chagiga 12A)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=13&daf=12&format=pdf) says that Adam was created as tall as one end of the heavens to the other (also described as from earth to the heavens), but after he sinned G-d made him smaller.

Rashi ([Baba Batra 75A](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=23&daf=75&format=pdf)) explains that when G-d made Adam smaller, he shrunk him to 100 Cubits.

Comment: Well the Hilton is not going to be able to accommodate him after Techiyat HaMeitim.

Answer (score 4):

One opinion brought on [Bava Batra 75a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=23&daf=75&format=pdf) says Adam was 100 cubits tall (approximately 150 ft).

Comment: 150 feet?? Are kidding me?

Comment: @MonikaMichael See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4037/759. (Also I edited your above comment for its tone.)

Answer (score 3):

Jewish tradition says that Adam was as tall as one end of the heaven to another.

Source: [Rashi, Devarim 4:32](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9968/showrashi/true#v32)