# Yibum against her will

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, women, yibbum-chalitza-levirate, masechet-yevamot

It says in Yevamos 53b among other places that Yibbum (levirate marriage to the wife of one's brother when a brother died childless) works against her will. So I was wondering if while it works is it assur to do it? Is it considered rape? Damaging her? Chillul Hashem? Violation of treat your friend like yourself? Etc?

Comment: This doesn't seem that different from the 'ordinary' case of marital rape (mentioned here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/46172/759 ). (I'm confused by "Is it considered rape?" since it is by definition exactly rape. What do you mean to ask there?)

Comment: I mean halachikly is it considered rape. Does the mitzvah of yibum 'over-ride' it? What about the rule of aseh docheh losaseh?

Comment: "halachikly is it considered rape" What is the halachik category of rape to which you refer? I don't know what you're talking about. "Rape" is just an English word. What is being overridden here?

Comment: You said which halachik category of rape I'm talking about. I replyed that I'm referring to the forced marital rape you referred to in your first comment and have a link to

Comment: What halachic category is forced marital rape? I said it was a "case" not a halachic category

Comment: The verse from Proverbs 19:2, “Also without consent, an improper soul; he who is hasty with his feet is a sinner,” is interpreted to mean that it is forbidden to force one’s wife in marital relations, the result being children of bad character. (Eruvin 100b, Kiddushin 13a, Yevamot 53b-54a) found it here-
 https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.myjewishlearning.com/the-torch/how-do-the-rabbis-in-the-talmud-address-rape/amp/    so my question is yibum have this issur as well

Comment: Interesting - the Mishna that discusses this is 6:1. Then 6:2, 3, 4  go on to discuss forbidden marriages - making it sound that 6:1 is not such a great idea.

Comment: @orion i think i have brought you a concrete answer that supports your notion that it should be forbidden against her will to do Yibbum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gemara Yevamos [52a](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.52a.4) says that it is forbidden Derabanan for one who does Yibbum (i.e relations) without Doing Maamar to the Yevama (which means giving her monetary value worth a *shave Pruta* like Kidushin) and this is equivalent to *Mekadesh bebiah* - matrimonial relations which is *Chayav Makas Mardus* - liable to rabbinic lashes:

> אמר רב הונא מצות יבמין מקדש ואחר כך בועל ואם בעל ועשה מאמר קנה אם בעל ועשה מאמר פשיטא דהא קניה בביאה אלא אימא באם בעל בלא מאמר קנה והתניא לוקה מכת מרדות גמדרבנן דרב מנגיד דמאן דמקדש בביאה

Since *Maamar* has to be done with the woman's consent Like Chachamim Yevamos [19b](https://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.19b.6), one cannot give the woman money against her will and since miderabanan one must do Maamar **it is forbidden to coerce the woman to do Yibbum** and so says the Rambam and Shulchan Aruch Even Haezer [166,3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.166.3).
Rambam Hilchos Yibbum [2,1](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/960620/jewish/Yibbum-vChalitzah-Chapter-Two.htm#v1):

> מדברי סופרים **שלא יבא היבם על יבמתו עד שיקדש אותה בפני שני עדים בפרוטה** או בש"פ וזהו הנקרא מאמר. ואין המאמר קונה ביבמה קנין גמור כמו הביאה **והעושה מאמר ביבמתו שלא מדעתה לא עשה כלום שאין האשה מתקדשת אלא ברצונה**

Comment: This is the correct answer - I am deleting mine - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/94300/501.