# Sefeikos and Mathematical Modelling

Tags: product-recommendation, safek, mathematics

I heard from a colleague that there exists a Sefer where the conclusions of Chazal on the status of certain Sefeikos can be represented in the form of [probability models](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/probint.htm)<sup>1</sup>.

Could anyone verify if this is certain?

<sup>1 <sub>The first topic discussed in the [Shev Shamaitsa](http://www.sefaria.org/Shev_Shmat'ta,_Shmatta_1.1?lang=en) is on the topic of Sefeikos and its details. That being said I am additonally interested in seeing if mathematical models can be created based on what is written by the Rishonim and Achromim on Sefeikos there.</sub></sup>

Comment: It seems strange because in sfekot chazaka is not really a statistical principle,  Kavua also is statistically similar to rov but follows an other rule.  There is mathematics in kinim,  in 5th perek of ktubot an Israeli mathematician wrote a mathematical model for a shvere mishna

Comment: This mathematician was premium Nobel of economy

Comment: Recommend you contact Professor Moshe Koppel at Bar-Ilan University. He would know.

Comment: @kouty http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/75657/8775.

Comment: What sort of mathematical models are you thinking of? Given the probability of each option occurring, does the psak follow the one that’s more likely?