# Technological advances of Yehoshua's generation over the natives

Tags: sources-mekorot, science

My question is based on ["were-rabbis-ahead-of-the-times"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22851/about-what-were-rabbis-ahead-of-the-times). A claim is made that the Torah contains scientific knowledge known to Rabbis and unknown to Gentiles.

Many try to bring examples from the Gemmorah and later Rabbis, but as all of them were well educated with general knowledge it is difficult to tell.

I thought about a simple "test": the Jewish nation received the Written as well as the Oral Torah in the wilderness and learned it for 40 years straight from Moses. It's fair to call them the best Torah scholars of them all (אם הראשונים כמלאכים).

When they entered the Promised Land, I would expect them to be more technologically/scientifically advanced than the native gentile nations in many areas - geometry, astronomy, medicine, agriculture, metallurgy etc allowing them to get better crops, lesser death rates, better weather prediction and more. As this knowledge would clearly prove advantageous, I would expect our sources to mention them.

So I'm looking for the sources in Na"KH that show that the Israelites had advanced techniques over the natives.